# Is a table cell valign property considered as an inline CSS style?

Tags: html, css

I've just encountered a weird bug/feature in table cells under Chrome & Firefox.

it seems a TD tag with valign=middle is overwritten by the vertical-align css property.

Check this jsfiddle example out: http://jsfiddle.net/8CDFq/1/

the first cell has valign=middle in the HTML part. All cells have the vertical-align:bottom property.

In Chrome's debug bar it shows the following:

[image]

look at the regions in red. it's lying! :D

My assumption was that valign vas considered as an inline style == wrong ?

Comment: It is very odd that the developer tools show it incorrectly like that, however if you look at the computed styles it does show the proper value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems a TD tag with valign=middle is overwritten by the vertical-align css property.

Yes. CSS trumps obsolete HTML attributes as per [section 6.4.4 of the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint)

Answer (score 4):

Using `valign` is not the same as using an inline style with the `style` attribute. It is rather a deprecated HTML attribute and its purpose is now delegated to the `vertical-align` CSS property.